# Batch Queries Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have doubt.
Is there any way to make batch queries?
I know I can use `$in` operator, but what if I need to batch an array of arrays? for example:

I have this array:

`[1, 2, 3]`

normal way using `$in` operator:

`UserModel.find( {"_id": { "$in": [ 1, 2, 3 ] } } )`

but what if I have this array:

```
 [
   [1, 2, 3],
   [4, 5, 6],
   [1, 3, 5]
 ]
```

how can I batch this array in one query?

this is an example of how I thought I could do this but it will take the complete array instead of each value. i tried with `$each` operator but it just work with `$addToSet` operator.

```
`UserModel.find( {"_id": { "$in": [ [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 4, 5, 6 ], [ 1, 3, 5 ]      ] } } )`
```

I thought about bulk operator but It is just available for mutations not for reads.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Wouldn't you just flatten that array of arrays so that `$in` would work? Not sure what you're looking to do, can you clarify your question?

Comment: I want to avoid multiple roundtrips. I am working with graphql in this case, and to resolve some queries I need to make a lot of queries. example:
if have an user who is member in many clubs. So, I want to resolve the clubs of the users I requested in the query. if I do something like this:

```query { 
                users {
                  id,
                   clubs {
                     id
                   }
                }
}``` It will resolve the files but requesting 1 by 1, and it turns in a ton of roundtrips

Comment: Ok, there isn't any batch query support that I know of.

Comment: I was looking for the entire web, I spent like 1 week trying to do something with all mongodb operators but no success. If mongodb allows bulk operations for queries would be awesome. Thanks for your time to answer my question dude.

Comment: @EduardoZ, I'm still curious why don't fatten out the arrays into single array as suggested in the above comment? Because that's what I got from your question. Perhaps you can edit and elaborate your requirement further. Maybe someone can help you make your queries efficient.

Comment: That is the question. Why don't just convert `[[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6],[1, 3, 5]]` to `[1,2,3,4,5,6,1,3,5]` and use `$in` operator?

Comment: I am using a batcher in graphql. So I need to return the same quantity of elements which has been asked. So, If I use  $in operator with `[1,2,3,4,5,6,1,3,5]` will return only 7 elements instead of 10 because there are some repeated elements. I did in that way you mentioned but doesnt solve my problem. thanks for the answer @talhaAwan

Comment: Got your point! Even in that case you can write a code that can give you exact no of elements in the same order as you provided in `$in` operator, even they are repeated.

Comment: Yes. I will give another try. if I find a solution I'll post here. thanks